# JavaFX show image near string in listview

Tags: java, image, listview, javafx, imageview

I want to show a message near a string in a listview i tried to look it up but i cant understand it pretty much i tried this from the website http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm at Example 11-4 Creating a Cell Factory i tried to convert it to imageview and it did work but a problem is i dont see a string, the image is not near the string and image is too big there should be a way to resize it soo can someone help me with showing a image near a string in listview? this is the code that i tried to convert:

Piece 1

```
static class ColorRectCell extends ListCell<String> {
        Image fileimg = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.png"));
        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            ImageView rect = new ImageView();
            if (item != null) {
                rect.setImage(fileimg);
                setGraphic(rect);
            }
        }
    }
```

Piece 2

```
FileExplorerFormSlaveFileListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, 
                ListCell<String>>() {

                    public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list) {
                        return new ColorRectCell();
                    }
                }
            );
```

I hope someone can help me its very important to me. Thanks. If you cant understand what i am asking tell me and i will try to format the question i am bad at explaining problems.

Comment: Can you post an image of what you get, and explain more clearly how it is different from what you want? It would also be helpful if you could edit the text in your question so that it is actually readable. (You could try, for example, using punctuation and breaking it into sentences.) As it is currently worded, it is extremely difficult to read and understand what you are asking.

Comment: I want it to look like a treeview that has a image near string in listview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cells](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListCell.html) are [Labeled](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html) nodes which can innately display both text and graphics, where the text is a label for an arbitrary graphic node.  So, in your cell, maintain a rendering for the graphic (an ImageView), and set both the graphic and text as appropriate in the [updateItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#updateItem-T-boolean-) implementation.

```
private ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

@Override
protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (empty || item == null) {
        imageView.setImage(null);

        setGraphic(null);
        setText(null);
    } else {
        imageView.setImage(
                imageCollection.get(
                        item
                )
        );

        setText(constructLabel(SHORT_PREFIX, item, SUFFIX));
        setGraphic(imageView);
    }
}
```

*Sample Application*

[image: imageview with labeled image]

Here, all of the possible images are pre-loaded and stored in a cache, which will work OK if you have a small number of images.  If you have a large number of images, you would probably want a more sophisticated LRU style cache for the images where newer images are loaded on demand in the background, possibly with a placeholder or progress indicator for the image while the background loading process is running.

In the sample application, the images are resized in the Image constructor so they are all the same height.  Also, the implementation is suited to a file type icon display because only a single image for any given file type will ever be created and that same image may be reused via different ImageViews used in different cells.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class LabeledList extends Application {

    private static final double IMAGE_HEIGHT = 36;

    private static final String SHORT_PREFIX =
            "bird";

    private static final String LONG_PREFIX =
            "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jozef89/origami-birds/72/" + SHORT_PREFIX;

    private static final String SUFFIX =
            "-icon.png";

    private static final ObservableList<String> birds = FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "-black",
                "-blue",
                "-red",
                "-red-2",
                "-yellow",
                "s-green",
                "s-green-2"
            )
    );

    private Map<String, Image> imageCollection;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        imageCollection = birds.stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                        bird -> bird,
                        bird -> new Image(
                                        constructLabel(LONG_PREFIX, bird, SUFFIX),
                                        0,
                                        IMAGE_HEIGHT,
                                        true,
                                        true
                                )
                )
        );

        ListView<String> birdList = new ListView<>(birds);
        birdList.setCellFactory(param -> new BirdCell());
        birdList.setPrefWidth(230);
        birdList.setPrefHeight(200);

        VBox layout = new VBox(birdList);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(LabeledList.class);
    }

    private class BirdCell extends ListCell<String> {
        private ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty || item == null) {
                imageView.setImage(null);

                setGraphic(null);
                setText(null);
            } else {
                imageView.setImage(
                        imageCollection.get(
                                item
                        )
                );

                setText(constructLabel(SHORT_PREFIX, item, SUFFIX));
                setGraphic(imageView);
            }
        }
    }

    private String constructLabel(String prefix, String bird, String suffix) {
        return (prefix != null ? prefix : "")
                + bird
                + (suffix != null ? suffix : "");
    }

    // Iconset Homepage: http://jozef89.deviantart.com/art/Origami-Birds-400642253
    // License: CC Attribution-Noncommercial-No Derivate 3.0
    // Commercial usage: Not allowed    

}
```

Comment: What if I create ObserableList of HBox and add image and text in that HBox?

Comment: @UnKnown I don't understand your additional question.  Perhaps create a new question and explain your question more thoroughly there.

Comment: I'm creating `ListView` of Image and Label by this.
`ObservableList<HBox> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
HBox hb = new HBox();
hb.getChildren().addAll(image,label);
data.add(hb);
ListView<HBox> list = new ListView<>(data);`

Is it fine? or I should override ListCell?

Comment: @UnKnown no, it is not fine, you should use a cell factory and not use nodes as ListView items.  You should create a new question instead of asking questions in comments and somebody could provide you with a more detailed answer to explain why this is so.